# How do I configure my Nuxt frontend application to know the baseUrl of the backend which uses Strapi?

Tags: vue.js, graphql, nuxt.js, apollo, strapi

I have been following these two tutorials:

- [Deliveroo clone - Nuxt/Apollo/Strapi](https://strapi.io/blog/cooking-a-deliveroo-clone-with-nuxt-vue-js-graphql-strapi-and-stripe-dishes-list-part-3-7/)
- [Blog - Nuxt/Apollo/Strapi](https://strapi.io/blog/build-a-blog-using-nuxt-strapi-and-apollo)

After [reading through Strapi's documentation](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/configurations.html#cron-tasks) and scouring the web I cannot figure out how to set a `baseUrl` of my application on the frontend so that whatever environment I am in will return the right URL to query the backend, for example:

- Production: `https://awesomesauce.com`
- Staging: `https://staging.awesomesauce.com`
- QA: `https://qa.awesomesauce.com`
- Dev: `http://localhost:1337`

If I was in staging then this `baseUrl` would be set to `https://staging.awesomesauce.com`, and so on.

For example in these tutorials you'll see when they reference images they do so like this `<img src="http://localhost:1337/img.jpg />`, however in a production environment how would this ever work?

Strapi's documentation has some information about using the `server.json`:

> As an example using this configuration with Nginx your server would respond to https://example.com:8443 instead of http://localhost:1337

I see that there is a `config/environments/` directory with `development`, `production`, and `staging`, I am lost with how I can access something from these like `strapi.currentEnvironment.baseUrl` from my frontend application in an `<img />` tag or elsewhere. My application is structured like this:

```
Application
├── frontend
├── backend
```

I make the queries from the frontend to the backend using Apollo.

Is there some sort of magic proxy thing going on where references to `localhost:1337` are redirected to their respective environment URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [ENV variables](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-env) in your Nuxt app and keep the values in different `.env` files in sync with your Strapi server settings....